ImportError with PyInstaller and scikit-learn
I'm currently facing an issue when trying to package a Python script that uses scikit-learn with PyInstaller. Specifically, I'm encountering an import error related to sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._datasets_pair when running the executable created by PyInstaller.
Interestingly, when I run the script directly in Python, everything works fine without any errors.
However, when I try to package this script using PyInstaller, I encounter the import error mentioned below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Heimdall.py", line 15, in <module>
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
   File "sklearn\cluster\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
   File "sklearn\cluster\_affinity_propagation.py", line 16, in <module>   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
   File "sklearn\metrics\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
   File "sklearn\metrics\cluster\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module   File "sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py", line 22, in <module>
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
   File "sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 43, in <module>
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
   File "sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
   File "sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\_dispatcher.py", line 13, in <module>
   File "sklearn\\metrics\\_pairwise_distances_reduction\\_argkmin.pyx", line 1, in init sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin
   File "sklearn\\metrics\\_pairwise_distances_reduction\\_base.pyx", line 1, in init sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._base
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._datasets_pair' [21156]
 Failed to execute script 'Heimdall' due to unhandled exception!

Has anyone else faced a similar issue when using PyInstaller with scikit-learn? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
Don't know what to do
